# How can map fusion be detected and applied

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In exercise 7.7 of FP in Scala, authors mention about

```
map(map(y)(g))(f) == map(y) (f compose g)
```

being a free theorem given,

```
map(y) (id) == y
```

As a corollary authors also mention that it can be used as an optimization technique using pattern matching. This chapter is about a functional library for parallel processing so optimization here essentially means instead of two parallel computations we can create just one.

So, given a type Par as below

```
type Par[A] = (es: ExecutorService) => Future[A]

implicit def toParOps[A](p: Par[A]): ParOps[A] = new ParOps(p)

class ParOps[A](p: Par[A]) {
//methods go here
}
```

How can we detect opportunities for map fusion and apply the optimization using pattern matching?

Comment: While the optimization is theoretically valid and possible, I don't know of any language / library that apply it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not quite sure how to even find out patterns to optimize. For example a match expression cannot descend on the structure of method invocations to find out patterns.